# What is the best monitor refresh rate (in Hz) to remove flickering when filming at 24 frames per second with a 1/50 shutter speed?

Tags: framerate

I tried setting the monitor to 50 Hz and 100 Hz, but I still see flickering. Everything looked fine when the monitor was set to 60 Hz and the shutter speed to 1/25. That being said, I am trying to respect the 180 rule to have natural motion blur.